# How to customize a dynamic, programmatic layout - Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, dynamic

I am dealing with some sample code I am using to create an app that pulls in Surveys from a server. The layout rendering is done in the java rather than in XML and I am having a problem having labels and text editing boxes (for questions and answers, respectively) squishing into eachother on the same line rather than sitting one on top of the other on seperate lines as is the default with rendering in XML.

I want to have the Labels above the text edit boxes so both can stretch across the screen and be seen better.

the code for the overall layout it here:

```
    private boolean DisplayForm()
{

    try
    {
        ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
        //need TableLayout Here!
        final LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        sv.addView(ll);
        ll.setOrientation(android.widget.LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        ll.setBackgroundResource(R.color.background);


        int i;
        for (i=0;i<theForm.fields.size();i++) {
            if (theForm.fields.elementAt(i).getType().equals("text")) {
                theForm.fields.elementAt(i).obj = new EditSurvey(this,(theForm.fields.elementAt(i).isRequired() ? "*" : "") + theForm.fields.elementAt(i).getLabel(),"");
                ll.addView((View) theForm.fields.elementAt(i).obj);
            }
            if (theForm.fields.elementAt(i).getType().equals("numeric")) {
                theForm.fields.elementAt(i).obj = new EditSurvey(this,(theForm.fields.elementAt(i).isRequired() ? "*" : "") + theForm.fields.elementAt(i).getLabel(),"");
                ((EditSurvey)theForm.fields.elementAt(i).obj).makeNumeric();
                ll.addView((View) theForm.fields.elementAt(i).obj);
            }
            if (theForm.fields.elementAt(i).getType().equals("choice")) {
                theForm.fields.elementAt(i).obj = new SurveySpinners(this,(theForm.fields.elementAt(i).isRequired() ? "*" : "") + theForm.fields.elementAt(i).getLabel(),theForm.fields.elementAt(i).getOptions());
                ll.addView((View) theForm.fields.elementAt(i).obj);
            }
        }
```

the code for pulling in the labels and text editing boxes is here:

```
public class EditSurvey extends LinearLayout {
TextView label;
EditText txtBox;

public EditSurvey(Context context,String labelText,String initialText) {
    super(context);
    label = new TextView(context);
    label.setText(labelText);
    label.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
    //label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    txtBox = new EditText(context);
    txtBox.setText(initialText);
    //txtBox.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    this.addView(label);
    this.addView(txtBox);
}
```

I've left out the other code snippet that pulls in the labels with spinners, which is pretty much the same.

This is not my code, just to be clear (it's Frank Abelson's), but I am trying to wrangle it to my purposes.

any help would be fantastic.

Comment: See if this.setOrientation(android.widget.LinearLayout.VERTICAL); in your EditSurvey class helps